# Spring hibernate validation

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, validation, spring-mvc

I'm solving a problem connecting with Hibernate validation. I got an exception `org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.OptionalValidatorFactoryBean#0': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.hibernate.validator.engine.ConfigurationImpl.getDefaultParameterNameProvider()Ljavax/validation/ParameterNameProvider;`

This is my code in the controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/student/result", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addStudent(@ModelAttribute("studentForm") @Valid Student student,
        ModelMap model, BindingResult result) {
    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        return "add";
    }
    model.addAttribute("message", "Student added successfully");
    model.addAttribute("student", student);
    return "result";
}
```

This is my part of the spring-servlet.xml

```xml
<mvc:annotation-driven />
<bean class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource"
      id="messageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="messages" />
</bean>
```

My dependencies

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.4.Final</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
    <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

I don't have idea what I'm doing wrong. I did it according to tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have invalid ordering of BindingResult and @ModelAttribute.
ModelAttribute is to be followed by BindingResult.
Try

```
 public String addStudent(ModelMap model, @ModelAttribute("studentForm") @Valid Student student, BindingResult result)
```

Answer (score 3):

The Hibernate validator dependency itself pulls the java validation API as a transitive dependency. From the docs:

"Project set up

In order to use Hibernate Validator within a Maven project, simply add the following dependency to your pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
   <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
   <version>5.2.4.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

This transitively pulls in the dependency to the Bean Validation API (javax.validation:validation-api:{bv_api})."

No need to declare the dependency yourself. However, your problem seems to be related with some Spring incompatibility with your Hibernate version:

> Error creating bean with name
>   'org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.OptionalValidatorFactoryBean#0':
>   Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.AbstractMethodError:
>   org.hibernate.validator.engine.ConfigurationImpl.getDefaultParameterNameProvider()Ljavax/validation/ParameterNameProvider;

Basically, I would bet that the Spring version you're using isn't compatible at all with Hibernate 5.

**See also:**

- [Getting started with Hibernate Validator](http://hibernate.org/validator/documentation/getting-started/)

Comment: Thank you. Which version should I use?

Comment: Take a look to the spring docs. You could either upgrade the spring version to ensure hibernate 5.x compatibility or downgrade hibernate to 4.x.